# How to create arbitrary binary file at the Windows 7 command line?

Tags: windows-7

How to create arbitrary binary file at the Windows 7 command line?
Without any extra installed tools, I could do this with the debug command in XP.  Now in Windows 7 I am stuck.  I want to type at the command line and create an arbitrary binary file.  Any ideas?

Comment: does a powershell script count as command line?

Comment: I don't think so.  I can't find powershell on my Windows 7 machine.  If I have to install powershell, then there are plenty of other things I could have installed.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/10/28/powershell-will-be-installed-by-default-on-windows-server-08-r2-ws08r2-and-windows-7-w7.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can create a meaningless binary file with the fsutil command, e.g.

```
fsutil file createnew filename.bin 1000
```

The last parameter is the desired file size in bytes.